# get first 10 characters of matched string --- PHP regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

In my site users can give links with double stars like: `**http://www.google.com**` I want to highlight this link using `preg_replace()`. I am able to catch exact link however i want first 10 character of this link to put at the middle of the `<a></a>` tags.

Heres the code:

```
$str = "http://www.example.com/dnvjndjnvjd";
$str = preg_replace('/\*\*(\S+)\*\*/', '<a href="$1">?#right there i want first 10 chracter of $1</a>', $str);
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be complex, use [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Comment: Replace $str instead and output it?

Comment: Use preg_replace_callback  and trim your match inside the anonymous function.

Comment: There are a few ways to do this. Maybe https://eval.in/627121

Comment: @JayBlanchard how should i use it on `$1`

Comment: @jjkk Use it inside the callback. You cannot perform a substr() directly on a `$1`

Comment: @chris85 how this thing worked? an explanation please

Comment: You know that will result in `http://www`.  Not very descriptive.

Comment: @jjkk `.` is any character `{}` is a number of characters. So `.{10}` is 10 characters.

Comment: Did you give up or what?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is like @chris85 says:

`$str = '**http://example.com/dnvjndjnvjd**';
echo preg_replace('/\*{2}([^\*]{10}).*\*{2}/', '$1', $str);`

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_replace_callback()`:

```
<?php

$string = "There is an URL in the middle of nowhere: **http://www.example.com/dnvjndjnvjd** and here's another one **http://www.example.com/ddadadada**";

$regex = '~\*{2}(https?://(?:www\.)?(\S+))\*{2}~';

$string = preg_replace_callback($regex,
    function($match) {
        return "<a href='{$match[1]}'>" . substr($match[2], 0, 10) . "</a>";
    },
    $string);

echo $string;
?>
```

---

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/w8PUXj).

Answer (score 0):

So just capture the entire thing in a capture group (replace with `$1`) and have a sub-group that only captures the first 10 (replace with `$2`):

```
$str = preg_replace('/\*\*((\S{10})\S*)\*\*/', '<a href="$1">$2</a>', $str);
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/NXZgpo_BIoKw4jB4)

Keep in mind though, with only 10 characters of multiple `http://www.domain.com` style entries, you'll only get `http://www`, which isn't very descriptive.